# Remove all but first character of a string in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query directly in MySQL to run through a series of records and replace the value of field with just the field character of the row.

e.g based on a column called formname

```
row 1 - Renault
row 2 - Citreon
row 3 - Jaguar
```

That will return..

```
row 1 - R
row 2 - C
row 3 - J
```

I can do this easily using native PHP functions but unsure how to do this using a native MYSQL function SUBSTR function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use left

```
update table
set column = left(column,1)
```

or for select you can write

```
select col1,left(col2,1)
from table
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd3620/1)

Comment: I suspect the OP really wants a `select` query and not an `update`.

Comment: Better yet, use `SELECT LEFT(column,1) ...`, but the idea is right.

Comment: PERFECT Khalid! +1 for the demo, will accept shortly

Answer (score 1):

To get this with the  [**SUBSTR()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function like you are asking for, you would use:

```
SELECT Field1, SUBSTR(field2, 1, 1) 
FROM MyTable
```

The function definition: `SUBSTR(str,pos,len)`